# c++ function create thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, function

I'm trying to do some threading in c ++ and I don't know why the first code works and the second one gives an error.

The first:

```
void a()
{
    while(1)
   {
       std::cout << "something" << std::endl;
   }
}
int main()
{
    std::thread th(a);
    while(1)
    {

    }
    return 0;
}
```

The second:

```
void b()
{
    while(1)
    {
        std::cout << "something" << std::endl;
    }
}
void a(){
{
    std::thread th(b);
}
int main()
{
    a();
    while(1)
    {
    
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Error:

libc++abi.dylib: terminating
Abort trap: 6

Comment: you have to call `join` on threads or they will terminate your program

Comment: Leaving `a` in 2 destructs the `th` object, which you may only do under certain conditions: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/%7Ethread

Comment: In the first code, the `std::thread` object stays alive while `main()` loops forever.  In the second code, the `std::thread` object goes out of scope and is destroyed without being `join()`'ed or `detach()`'ed first, so `std::thread`'s destructor calls `std::terminate()` to kill the process.

Comment: @RemyLebeau So the problem is that the thread ends because the function a ends? (i don't want to join the threads)

Comment: When `a()` exits, the actual thread does not end, only the `th` variable goes out of scope, thus calling the `std::thread` destructor.  The thread is still running, hence the error, since you do not `join()` the thread to wait for it to end, or `detach()` to let it keep running without the `std::thread` owning it anymore. If you don't want to `join()` the thread, then you have to `detach()` it. `std::thread` can't be destructed while it is still owning a *running* thread.